# PHPUnit. Протестировать ветку кода, которая зависит от настроек php.ini, неизменяемых в runtime

Tags: php, phpunit

## Предыстория

На некоторых "не_очень_хороших" хостингах любят безальтернативно отключать некоторые функции через `php.ini`. В частности иногда полезную `parse_ini_file`. В своем проекте (легковесный скелет api) обошел таким образом:

```
if (function_exists('parse_ini_file')) {
    self::$settings = parse_ini_file(PROPERTIES);
    return;
}
$content = preg_grep("/^[\w .]+=.*/", explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents(PROPERTIES)));
foreach ($content as $row) {
    $row                    = strstr($row . ';', ';', true);
    $key                    = trim(strstr($row, '=', true), " \n\r");
    $value                  = trim(strstr($row, '=', false), " \"=\n\r");
    self::$settings[ $key ] = $value;
}
```

## Вопрос

Как мне теперь прикрутить `PHPUnit` для тестирования куска кода с рукописным парсером?

Идеально было бы задисейблить ее в рантайме, но можно ли это сделать я как-то инфы не нашел.

PS Собственно я нахожусь в самом начале изучения `PHPUnit` и, возможно, есть true way, которого просто не знаю.

Comment: @rjhby Я не сразу понял суть вопроса, не успел удалить комментарий.

Comment: А тестировать будете на своем сервере? Если да, то можно попробовать http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php или rename_function

Comment: @ilyaplot APD переопределяет, а не удаляет. Для локального можно `runkit` использовать. Я хотел Travis к github прикрутить и тестировать там уже. Да и если вдруг кто использовать будет, то зависимости от `PECL` совершенно не нужны

Comment: Решение этого вопроса в любом случае добавит условий. Это либо PECL, либо конфигурация. Через ini_set точно не выйдет отключать функции, даже через htaccess такое не сделать.

Comment: Напишите тест, который будет сравнивать результат выполнения нативной функции и самописной. А дальше будет все равно, какими методами читается INI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зашел с черного хода.

Вынес самописный парсер в отдельный приватный метод

```
private static function loadSettings() {
    self::$settings = function_exists('parse_ini_file')
        ? parse_ini_file(PROPERTIES)
        : self::loadSettingsHard();
}

private static function loadSettingsHard() {
    $settings = [];
    $content  = preg_grep("/^[\w .]+=.*/", explode("\n", file_get_contents(PROPERTIES)));
    foreach ($content as $row) {
        $row              = strstr($row . ';', ';', true);
        $key              = trim(strstr($row, '=', true), " \n\r");
        $settings[ $key ] = trim(strstr($row, '=', false), " \"=\n\r");
    }

    return $settings;
}
```

В тестовом методе применил грязный хак с Reflection

```
public function testGetConfigValueHard() {
    $method = new ReflectionMethod(
        Config::class, 'loadSettingsHard'
    );
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    $method->invoke(Config::class);
    $this->assertEquals(
        'localhost',
        Config::get('db_host')
    );
}
```

В общем и целом, эта задача позволила меня посмотреть на тестирование с неожиданной стороны. Для покрытия тестами данного функционал я был вынужден уменьшить цикломатическую сложность своего кода (по факту применил принцип единственной ответственности), что является одним из столпов хорошей архитектуры приложения.

Что же до ответа на вопрос, то удалить функцию в рантайме можно с помощью функции [runkit_function_remove](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.runkit-function-remove.php), которая входит в `PECL` расширение `runkit`. По многим причинам такой подход нежелателен.